# AWS apt install error = Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using Amazon Linux AMI (2017.03.1) on a p2.xlarge instance, and attempting to sudo apt install {somepackage}, I get the following error:

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

I have already tried

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

and

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Comment: Did this happen straight after you launched it? Do you know what casued the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Solution:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install {somepackage}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. First look for that process *by*

> sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock

2. Then make sure the process is not running *by*

> ps cax | grep PID      #PID is the Process id e.g 1111

3. If PID is shown(It's running) kill it {else go to step 5} *by*

> sudo kill -9 PID

4. Make sure the process is killed done *by*

> sudo ps cax | grep PID

5. Then remove the locked file *by*

> sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
>
> sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend  #optional

6. **Finally** make dpkg fix its self *by*

> sudo dpkg --configure -a

[Reference From](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219545/dpkg-error-dpkg-status-database-is-locked-by-another-process)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the image you are using, it may be installing some dependencies at first run.
Try: `ps aux | grep -i apt` if it returns something like:

```
root      2531  0.0  0.0   4624   772 ?        Ss   23:34   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
root      2547  0.0  0.0   4624  1716 ?        S    23:34   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held install
```

or similar, you may want to wait until all necessary updates will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Note that instances can be configured to have "UserData" script to run on provisioning... That can cause things to be installed and the lock to be busy for a while.

I had a similar problem and after some investigation found the following in the "UserData" section of my instance template:

```
#cloud-config
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
runcmd:
- yum install -y amazon-efs-utils
- apt-get -y install amazon-efs-utils
- yum install -y nfs-utils
- apt-get -y install nfs-common
- file_system_id_1=fs-74aa550f
- efs_mount_point_1=/mnt/efs/fs1
- mkdir -p "${efs_mount_point_1}"
- test -f "/sbin/mount.efs" && printf "\n${file_system_id_1}:/ ${efs_mount_point_1} efs tls,_netdev\n" >> /etc/fstab || printf "\n${file_system_id_1}.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:/ ${efs_mount_point_1} nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport,_netdev 0 0\n" >> /etc/fstab
- test -f "/sbin/mount.efs" && grep -ozP 'client-info]\nsource' '/etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.conf'; if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then printf "\n[client-info]\nsource=liw\n" >> /etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.conf; fi;
- retryCnt=15; waitTime=30; while true; do mount -a -t efs,nfs4 defaults; if [ $? = 0 ] || [ $retryCnt -lt 1 ]; then echo File system mounted successfully; break; fi; echo File system not available, retrying to mount.; ((retryCnt--)); sleep $waitTime; done;
```

This is what was causing the lock for about 80-90 seconds on startup.

I removed this script from the template and I can now immediately use `apt-get`.

Comment: You should cite your source. Looks like you got it from: https://securitywing.com/how-to-permanently-auto-mount-eff-volume-to-ec2-instance-using-user-data/